# calling a method from main method to display values

Tags: java

```
public class Display {

    private int tab;
    public int getTab() {
        return tab;
    }
    public void setTab(int tab) {
        this.tab = tab;
    }

    public void displayTables(){
        int j,a;
        for(j=1;j<11;j++){
            a=getTab()*j;
            System.out.println(a);
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Display d=new Display();
        d.setTab(3);
        new Display().displayTables();

    }


}
```

when i execute the above code i am getting 0 as output instead of multiples of 3.....can someone point out where i have gone wrong...

Comment: You don't generally need use setters/getters to access private fields from within the same class. You can just access them directly eg `a = tab * j`. In this case you don't even need the `a`, you can just call `System.out.println(tab * j)`.

Comment: You can also declare the variable `j` in the for loop as well using `for(int j = 1; j < 11; j++) {...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a different instance of `Display` which has not had the variable `tab` set so its using the default value of `0` used for numeric primitives

```
d.displayTables();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using different instance for setting tab value and displaying table.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Display d=new Display();
    d.setTab(3);
   d.displayTables();

 }
```